# How to filter out GC_CURRENT logs from logcat in Android Studio

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, logcat

I have too many of this 'GC_CURRENT' logs filing my log cat view, which makes the real log from app hard to see. Is there some way I can do to filter them out? Thank you!

Comment: create your own custom filter by Tag, Name, PID, Application Name

Answer (score 0):

I use an app called CatLog which has really great filter support for easily parsing your recent LogCat activity.

[image]